# How to get the folder ID from an Azure data storage container?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I created a folder called `test` in a data storage container as shown in the image below:

[image]

This folder is used by a logic app that I created and I noticed in the code that it needs the `folder id` to work properly (see the code below):

```
"resources":
  [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('workflows_App_name')]",
      "location": "westus2",
      "properties":
        {
          "state": "Enabled",
          "definition":
            {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters":
                { "$connections": { "defaultValue": {}, "type": "Object" } },
              "triggers":
                {
                  "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)":
                    {
                      "recurrence": { "frequency": "Second", "interval": 10 },
                      "evaluatedRecurrence":
                        { "frequency": "Second", "interval": 10 },
                      "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                      "type": "ApiConnection",
                      "inputs":
                        {
                          "queries":
                            {
                              "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                              "folderId": "JTJmb3B0aWDFWRUITTW5zZm9ybWVkLWRhdGEtZnMlMmZ0ZXN0JTJmdGVzd15GHTY9sb2dpYyUyZg=",
                              "maxFileCount": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
           ....
        ]
```

`"folderId": "JTJmb3B0aWDFWRUITTW5zZm9ybWVkLWRhdGEtZnMlMmZ0ZXN0JTJmdGVzd15GHTY9sb2dpYyUyZg=",`

This code was generated thanks to the Logic App UI but I will deploy this template parameterized in production and I won't be able to create the logic app through the UI. I need to find the `folder id` of the new folder that I will create in my production container. `folder id` is the last value that I need to deploy this template to production.

Where can I find this folder ID value? I tried to look into the storage explorer with no success, though.

Comment: It seems the `folderId` is the URL escaped base64 encoded value of the folder path. Can you try that?

Comment: You can get Id from the `get blob metadata using path` connector. As @GauravMantri mentioned it is the folder path in base64 encoded value.

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT - Please add your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri and @SwethaKandikonda-MT are right. The folder ID is the folder ID location escaped base64. This is the output that I received when I decoded this folder ID: 
`%2feventconnector-transformed-data-fs%2ftest%2ftesting_logic%2f`
Do you have any ideas why I have this `%2f` values at the beginning?

Comment: `%2f` is the escaped value of `/` (default delimiter).

Comment: This is some seriously dumb API design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve Id by using the `get blob metadata using path` connector to get blob metadata. That's the folder path in base64 encoded value.

Below Screenshot can help you in getting the right information
[image]

Another solution is to decode that ID manually and this will generate the location of your folder, something like this:

[image]

Thanks for the solution @GauravMantri and @SwethaKandikonda-MT.

Another alternative is to add a `compose` connector and decode the id.
`decodeBase64(body('Get_Blob_Metadata_using_path_(V2)')?['Id'])`

[image]